# Insert variable values to variable columns in MySql & python

Tags: python, mysql

I have two lists.

one a list of output strings from a sensor.
eg

```
output = "1,2,3,4,5,6"
output = output.split (',')
```

the second list is the column headers

```
columns = "date,time,name,age,etc,etc2"
columns = columns.split (',')
```

the order of the columns variable changes as do the output values.

I want to upload the date to mysql using columns variable to dictate the fields and outputs variable for the values.

this is my code which does not see columns as a list only as a single value?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from device import output
from device import columns

mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="", passwd="", db="")
cursor = mydb.cursor()

with mydb:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO logging(columns) '\
         'VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', output)
```

error given

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./upload4.py", line 27, in <module>
    'VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', output)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1136, "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1")
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You are using more values than second argument (`output`) can provide

Answer (score 0):

The query should be built in this way:

> 'INSERT INTO logging({}) VALUES({})'.format(','.join(columns), ','.join(['%s'] * len(columns)))